# Issue with Redis removing breadcrumbs

Tags: cache, ee-1.12, block-cache, breadcrumbs, redis

For some reason Redis seems to be removing breadcrumbs from the product view. As soon as I flush Redis they reappear for a while then disappear again.

Does anyone know of an issue with Redis with regards to breadcrumbs or does anyone know of an affective way to hole punch the breadcrumbs so they aren't cached?

Comment: I believe this is (used to be?) a problem with the Enterprise FPC, caching backend shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes I do now believe that the issue is with Enterprise FPC not Redis. Following this http://www.kingletas.com/2013/02/magento-fpc-breadcrumb-dissapearing.html seemed to fix the issue.